# Can't hide scroll bar and mantain div scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to follow the guides I've found here, but I am not being able to hide scroll bar and keeping the ability to scroll!

I've tried having the parent relative and the child absolute and `overflow:hidden` on the parent and `overflow-y:scroll` on the child but to no avail.

Right now I have:

```
parent
{
width: 100%;
padding-left: 30px;
height: 100%;   
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: hidden;
}
child
{   
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I've tried everything, but can't find why it's not working. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
*{margin:0;}
#container1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body{
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"><div id="container2">
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    good<br/>bye.
</div><div>
```